# Shutdown computer at specific time programmatically

Tags: vb6

I need an application with a feature that user should be able to set time of computer automatic shutdown (closing all opened applications) in visual basic 6.

I just need to know is this doable? if yes, what specific topics should I search? honestly, never did system programs in vb just m a db programmer that too of a primitive nature. (so gurus, thanks for understanding ;)

Comment: Does the program run in the background?

Answer (score 0):

```
Option Explicit 

Declare Function ExitWindowsEx Lib "user32" (ByVal uFlags As Long, ByVal dwReserved As Long) As Long 

Public Const EWX_FORCE = 4 
Public Const EWX_LOGOFF = 0 
Public Const EWX_REBOOT = 2 
Public Const EWX_SHUTDOWN = 1 

Public Sub Main() 
 Dim Res As Long 

 MsgBox ("Your System Will Now Shutdown") 

 Res = ExitWindowsEx(EWX_SHUTDOWN, 0) 

End Sub
```

[source](http://www.dreamincode.net/code/snippet3482.htm)

this does the job as required by you.